# KeyEvent handling in android?

Tags: android, events, key

I want to programattically handle the ENTER key in android.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Please Help!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to carefully override the following function:

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        {
            //your Action code
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [onKey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) to capture the key. `KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER` is used for the numeric ENTER key, and `KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER` is the Directional Pad Center key.