# Executing a method by tapping a physical button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a device that has a physical button on the side, when i tap the button it "execute" a custom intent, I'd like to execute a custom function in my application every time the user taps that button, is it possibile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch keypress with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261914/catch-keypress-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : [KeyEvent handling in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631977/keyevent-handling-in-android)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2262020/8513494

You must do something like the answer above, but instead of KeyEvent.KEY_CODE_ENTER use the constant corresponding to the desired button.

To see more details:
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent